# What would prevent a soul transfer into an immortal body from working?

Tags: magic

I'm Dante, an alchemist who has survived for hundreds of years by using a philosophers stone. This stone is made up of the innocent souls of thousands of people. It allows me to transfer my soul into different younger bodies, giving me a way to cheat death. However, the bodies that I inhabit begin to rot quicker than the previous one, forcing me to create new stones to extend my life. I have created artificial beings called  homunculi to help me gather the ingredients to create a stone. These creatures are immortal human constructs that are based off of the seven deadly sins ( lust, pride, gluttony, sloth, greed, envy, and wraith) , just because I think it is funny.

But wait...I just found the solution to my problem! Instead of transferring my soul into different bodies only for them to rot, I can simply transfer my soul into one of these homunculi! They do not age, are immune from wear and tear, and are incapable of rotting. This idiotic oversight has me slapping myself, because I spent centuries trying to solve a problem when the solution was right in front of me the entire time.

My plan should work, as it has been proven before by some moronic kid who accidentally transfered their soul into a suit of armor. What problem could arise to prevent this strategy from working with an immortal homunculus?

Comment: Homunculi are as ugly as sin (it's also your fault for basing on the seven deadly sins, but the originals were already really ugly), they're short and look like their growth was stunted. You may be immortal as a homunculus, but you will look really horrible.

Comment: What are these homunculi made of? More importantly what is the Philosopher's stone made of? ;D

Comment: What's life without life's little pleasures? Homunculi bodies do not feel. They don't see color. The food tastes bland. Touch? No touch sensation, only feelings of coldness or hotness. Or they feel severe chronic pain in their internal organs. Or they feel itchy all the time. Or maybe, they don't have any of those problems but any Omega trying to possess them suddenly develops them. Forever. Like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fzXmJyolfY

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Homunculi are not suits of armor.  Their bodies are occupied.**

You are disdainful of the homunculi because you created them using your art.  Your creations are more complex than you realize.  You know they are sentient because they follow your commands.  Their sentience is an emergent property and one you did not design, but which arose by virtue of how you created them.  This sentience is inextricably linked with the body it inhabits.  There is no such thing as a homunculus corpse.

You are used to transferring your soul into vacant husks, or human bodies in which your powerful spirit can easily evict the former owner.  The homunculi are a different matter entirely.  Your soul will find itself a guest in the house of a powerful and alien spirit.  Hopefully you treated it well when you were its master.  You are master no longer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the way I see it, there are two routes you could go.

### 1. The Homonculi are physiologically different.

While they have a basically human form, the Homonculi are quite different on the inside. As a result, while you can take complete control of it with ease, you can't just get up and walk away.

**"What about the kid possessing a suit of armor?!"**
Well, that kid is just a random duffer who had an accident. Unlike Dante, the mortal enemy of thousands of people (the families of your past hosts and those who went into your soul-stone), this kid had plenty of time to re-learn how to move. In addition, a suit of armor is comparatively simple; all the kid had to learn was how to move a few squeaky joints. Dante, on the other hand, has to re-learn how to manipulate every individual muscle.

**It's quite probable that the Homonculi have Vulcan reflexes (i.e, none.)** While this might sound like a comparatively minor difference, tell that to Dante when he suddenly realizes that "Oh ****, my heart isn't beating and I don't know how to operate it."

### 2. There's a big "NO VACANCY" sign on the door.

Another route you can go is to have the Homonculi already have a spirit, despite Incognito's attempting to make a spirit-less being. **Nota Bene: While interesting, this route is a little weird.**

To explain this route I need to go into some Platonic philosophy. In Platonism, everything in the physical world is a shadow of a "Form" which exists on higher plane ("Formland"). There are forms for all things, both physical (beavers and bees) and metaphysical (universal concepts like the Seven Deadly Sins).

The only exception to this rule is humanity; we are unique. Unlike the animals, which are merely reflections of Forms (the Perfect Beaver -> beavers, the Perfect Bee -> bees), we are a "mortal coil."  In other words, we are made up of two parts; a body (which is a reflection of the Perfect Human) and a soul. Importantly, this soul is itself a Form which has been consigned to inhabit a body (I did warn you that this would be weird).

**"How does this relate to being unable to possess Homonculi?"**
As I said above, the "mortal coil" which is humanity is a shadow combined with a Form. Per Daron's answer, the homonculi are primarily spirit creatures. Therefore, if Dante were to try possessing a homonculi he would find it rather crowded; there's already a soul in that coil.

**An advantage of going this route is that it explains why host bodies don't last very long.** One of the Platonic beliefs about mortal coils is that they are a bit like Uranium; they are unstable. As a result, the coil fissions in a process we call "death". Now, one of the things you said in your question is that Incognito does not kill the other person's soul; he just suppresses it. As a result, when Incognito takes over somebody's body he overloads the mortal coil, severely decreasing its half-life.

Answer (score 2):

It will work. It will work just as intended. You're going to transfer your soul into an immortal body. But I wouldn't call it living. I'd call it surviving.

Because what's life without life's little pleasures? Some or most of those are missing when Omega soul takes over the Homunculi body.

Homunculi bodies do not feel. They don't see color or are extremely shortsighted or both. The food tastes bland. Touch? No touch sensation, only feelings of coldness or hotness.

Or they feel severe chronic pain in their internal organs. Or they feel itchy all the time. Or maybe, they don't have any of those problems but any Omega trying to possess them suddenly develops them. Forever. Like this: [youtube.com/watch?v=1fzXmJyolfY](http://youtube.com/watch?v=1fzXmJyolfY)

Omega thinks "What a sad Homunculi life is! They don't feel the taste of food. They are in pain all the time. Good thing is they never felt any better, so they don't know what they are missing!"

But the truth is, Homunculi don't have those problems. Only after you take over their bodies they start to happen. Compared to that, aging at twice the rate as normal human is paradise. You get 15 years at full power, another 10 active years and 10 years practically bedridden, but you feel everything like a human does.

Answer (score 2):

**You designed your Homunculi to leave no corpses.**

For soul transfer with humans you must first magically remove the soul from the body without damaging the body. Then before the body dies you transfer your soul into it.

If you try this with homunculi you find that once the soul is removed the "body" disappears, leaving nothing to transfer into.

This is because Homunculi are primarily spirit creatures, that interact with the physical world by temporarily manifesting physical form. They cannot do this if they are dead.

You did this on purpose. If you send a minion on a mission that goes wrong and it is killed, better to have no evidence linking it back to you.

Answer (score 1):

The homunculi are *immortal,* they can't die. This ever-flowing spring of vitality prevents Dante from possessing their bodies. Think of a Homonculi as a hairdryer and Dante as a ping-pong ball that wants to go inside; as long as power goes into the hairdryer air comes out and keeps Dante from going inside.

Alternatively, Dante doesn't do it because the homunculi *are all connected!* In other words, while the homunculi have separate bodies, they are in reality a gestalt entity, linked by magic. If Dante were to attempt a soul transfer into one, his spirit would be split into seven pieces, one for each homunculus.

This would backfire because the homunculi *also* represent the seven sins; the transfer would turn the homunculi into separate individuals, manifestations of the seven deadly sins for Dante. One would represent Dante's many, many lifetimes of sloth; another an equivalent amount of pride. The two would have such different philosophies and ways of doing things that chances are they won't work together.

In essence, method 2 would **kill Dante;** he'd technically survive, but not in the way he wants. His Envy would be so laser-focused on getting what it wants that it wouldn't do anything else, and the same would go for each other homunculi.